# How to use cause in this situation?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct?

1. The sun damages your skin and *causes* lots of illness.
2. The sun damages your skin, *causing* lots of illness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second one is better, because the first one sounds like blaming the sun for the diseases :)

Answer (score 0):

Better to say, "The sun damages your skin, which causes many illnesses." In this way, "which" attaches to the whole of the main clause.

"Lots of illness" is wrong.